# Object youtube embed not working in Firefox

Tags: html, object, firefox, embed

So for some reason, I'm having issues making my object embed work on Firefox, but it works on all other browsers such as Chrome, Edge, etc..

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<object width="640" height="400">
                      <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X29_UP1FWVQ">
                      <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X29_UP1FWVQ" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="400">
                    </object>
```

Does anyone know if something special has to be passed for Firefox?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `object` and not `video`?

Comment: @FluffyKitten, `<video>` tags don't work for YouTube embeds unfortunately, or I would and I don't want to use `<iframe>` tags.

Comment: OK, I didn't realise it didn't work with YouTube, I usually use iframes :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten, I actually just learned that also :) - We have a system that renders `<iframe>` tags differently in our code, so for a work around I have to use `<object>` tags  - I don't know too much about them, but I don't see a downside.

Comment: No I can't think of any downsides either, its a long time ago now but I used them for including different video formats for different browsers. (Nowadays I stick everything on Vimeo!)

Comment: @FluffyKitten, I truly do appreciate your help and input also! You've previously helped me on things and I am so grateful!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, you need an `data=""` attribute on the object for this to work.